# Match all of the values specified in an array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

so i want to run a mongoose query to find posts where all the searcharray tags are present.

The tags vary in amount.

Currently this returns posts where any of the tags are present.

```
Post.find({
        'tags.name': { 
            $in : searcharray
        }
    }, function(err, post) {

        console.log(post);

    }
);
```

I checked the docs and couldn't quite piece this one together.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/), which is basically an `$and` operation with shorter syntax much as `$in` is an `$or` operation with shorter syntax:

```
Post.find({"tags.name": { "$all": searcharray } }, function(err, posts) {
        console.log(posts);
});
```

That requires that your "tags" array has members matching "name" for "all" of the items specified in the `searchArray` list.

As an "or" condition the `$in` whould just recall any documents that contained at least one of the items, so the "and" condition means all of the items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of the [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operator.

```
Post.find({
        'tags.name': { 
            $all : searcharray
        }
    }, function(err, post) {

        console.log(post);

    }
);
```